# Raspberry Pi with java programing - Jar does not run

Tags: java, swing, raspberry-pi

I want to use a Raspberry Pi 3 to host a server for a game I am making.

I tried using the built-in bluej ide to make a Hello World app that opens a simple JFrame. When I made it into a jar and launched it, it asked me what program to use to open the file. Shouldn't a jar launch without using a program to open it?

What am I doing wrong? How can I execute a jar on my Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Technically, the program used to run .jar files is Java.  You can also open .jar files with a zip program, because .jar files are plain ZIP files.

What does the list contain?  Is there a "Java" option?

Comment: you still need java and run `java -jar filename.jar` to run it